# Share thirdparty audio link in sound cloud and youtube in android application

Tags: android, audio, youtube, share, soundcloud

I have a online music player application. Music files are being uploaded to our server. Please help me to share these songs in sound-cloud and youtube.

```
http://serverip:port/uploads/audio/filename.mp3
```

When I do search in google, found that these both are cloud storage space and need to upload files to share, but our project design allows us to upload file only to our server. so is there any hope to share a thirdparty audio-link in soundcloud and youtube from my android application.

Thanks in advance..